# FAA Commercial Pilot Knowledge Test: Sign Question

Tags: airport-markings, faa-knowledge-test

This image appears in the FAA Test Supplement *Commercial Test FAA-CT-8080-1E* but I am unable to find it in the AIM or the Pilot’s Handbook of Aeronautical Knowledge. I looks like *a don’t taxi here* pavement marking, but I’d like confirmation of my guess.

The closest I can get to an official explanation is in the AIM 2-3-2 b

> Markings for taxiways, areas not intended for use by aircraft (closed
>   and hazardous areas), and holding positions (even if they are on a
>   runway) are yellow.

But the examples don’t match this graphic.

[image: Commercial Knowledge Test Image]

Answer (score 18):

This sign is a taxiway ending marker.  I retrieved this graphic from the [CFI Notebook Website.](https://www.cfinotebook.net/notebook/aircraft-operations/terminal/airport-markings-and-signs)

[image]

Comment: Knowing what it is called helped me find it, It is in Appendix C of the Pilot's Handbook.